# Unable to edit my module

Tags: sitecore-marketplace

There seems to be few problems with the Sitecore marketplace site.
First, the save option was broken. Nothing was happening on clicking Save & I was also unable to add metadata to the module.

Later this appears to be fixed. I did upload my package & added the description & pictures.
Then the publish option did not work.

Now, the status says - it is under construction & I do not see an edit option.
Also, the uploaded package is gone and so are the pictures.

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/M/Minions__Sitecore_Developer_Tools.aspx

Also, I did not receive any email that this module is being reviewed.

I have emailed Mark Van Aalst & also tried contacting on slack but did not receive any reply.

Is there any other support group email that I can contact for this.

Please advice.

[image]

Comment: The Marketplace site has become antique and obsolete and that is the reason this year's HACKATHON asked for ideas for the new site. I will not be surprised if we see a new Marketplace site very soon based on HACKATHON ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This is a site owned by Sitecore, not the community. Only they will be able to help resolve any issues or bugs with the site.

You should email the relevant owners of the site and seek help. There is a link to an email in the footer of the marketplace site, you should contact this email instead. The link currently points to [marketplace@sitecore.net](http://marketplace@sitecore.net)

[image: email link]